# Cartoon Movie about a big robot that help fight aliens

Tags: animation, story-identification, movie

It starts off with an alien abduction, not sure but might be the parents of the protagonist. I remember the main character being maybe 16 years old as he is riding a motor cycle and playing Football (american). There are other protagonist that each fly in a separate spaceship that can assemble to one big one. They have a big robot that is stored under water. I believe it is red and white but not sure. I remember it had a Typhoon attack. Can anyone identify this?

**EDIT:** to add some more information, I watched it on VHS, not sure the release date but guessing before 1990. I'm guessing it is from america. The characters are all white I believe.

There were one girl and 4 boys as main characters. they were wearing different colors. The protagonist was wearing red and I think the leader of the gang was blue. A scene: the protagonist was playing football but suddenly he left the court and drove off in a motorcycle, think he got a vision or something that made him leave.

**Another scene/plot:** I remember the protagonist leaving the rest of the gang to go and do something by himself but got scolded by the leader since they can't fight as well with only 4. Can't remember a ton about the aliens, but I think they had big green buildings that was a half sphere sticking out of the ground and had a green beam they used to attack with.

Comment: Parts of this seem a lot like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers_(film)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like Voltron to me. There's Voltron the movie from 1984 and another from 1986. One girl and 4 boys, red wearing main character, blue leader... I am not certain about football part. Please check it out.

Edit: It was similar to Voltron. It was actually Voltes V.

Comment: I looked up Voltron, that was not it but found: Voltes V I think that was it! Thank you :)

Comment: Please vote it as accepted answer.

Comment: jo1storm, the OP found out the name of the cartoon by himself, it was not what you were suggesting. He could write and accept a self-answer, if he is so inclined, not accepting an answer pointing to the wrong name.

Comment: Agreed. I just don't like questions with no accepted answers. :D I pointed him in the right direction, on the animedb it is literally on the list: voltes V, voltron.